# @NamedQuery : identification variable 'sysdate' is not defined in the FROM clause

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I tried to look for it but could not resolve. need your thoughts on this

**I am using this NamedQuery in getting results from the Db.**

```
@NamedQuery(name= "Person.FindByCodeAndFiscalYear", 
            query="select o from Person o where o.fiscalYear=:pfiscalYear and o.Code=:pCode and (o.desactivatedDate is null or o.desactivatedDate > sysdate)")
```

**here I want the column desactivateDate to be either null or sysdate**

**error while compiling code :**

```
Caused By: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select o from Person o where o.fiscalYear=:pfiscalYear and o.Code=:pCode and (o.desactivatedDate is null or o.desactivatedDate > sysdate)]. 
[144, 151] The identification variable 'sysdate' cannot be used in conjunction with the > operator.
[144, 151] The identification variable 'sysdate' is not defined in the FROM clause.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.JPAQuery.processJPQLQuery(JPAQuery.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.JPAQuery.prepare(JPAQuery.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persiste
```

Comment: Thanks folks, got the answer . we can use CURRENT_DATE in place of sysdate

Answer (score 0):

SYSDATA is Oracle specific where as CURRENT_DATA is SQL and JPQL standard.